# How do I animate a UILabel inside a UITableViewCell after reloadData()?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm creating a form and whenever a user forgets to fill out a form field, I have a mechanism to highlight the required text labels for any of the cells in which the user did not select a value in. After the color change is reflected and the tableView is reloaded, I want to animate the highlighted label(s) also. What is the proper way to achieve this? The tableView can load a mixture of custom tableViewCells, so I want to know this can be done across all the custom cells.

Please note: Labels are highlighted in red if missing on "Submit" button click. As the missing fields are filled out, the labels are no longer highlighted as soon as they have a value assigned to that field. So now I need a way to animate the individual labels on the cells that are of different custom cell classes only when the user attempts to click the submit button with missing fields

Comment: Why are you reloading the whole table?  You should only do this if there is a substantial change in your table data.  You should reload the relevant cells or just get a reference to the cell if it is visible and perform the required updates.

Comment: I have an internal data model saving the state of the table view. The data model is loaded from a backend service's JSON response so it's difficult to say when a particular cell will load and in what order.

Comment: Still. You should put some effort into avoiding an entire table reload if possible. When you get the data for a given cell you should be able to perform a reload of just that cell, or retrieve the cell using `cellForRowAt`  if you get a cell back you know it is on screen and you can animate it. If you get nil it is offscreen and you can ignore it; it will be refreshed when the user scrolls

Answer (score 3):

`Protocols`

You can create a protocol that your custom cells will implement, so in each custom cell you can make your own implementation of a function that you will call in the delegate method from the table view:

```
     tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
                   forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      guard let customCellThatImplementsFormCell = cell as? FormCell else { return }

/// check if has errors and call either function 

}
```

depending on if your cell has an error or not

this is a very simple idea but it could look like this

```
protocol FormCell {
 func showError()
 func hideError()
}


class FormTextInputCell: UITableViewCell {

}

extension FormTextInputCell: FormCell {

  func showError() {
    // Style the cell and animate what you want
 }

 func hideError() {
    // Style the cell and animate what you want
 }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood what you mean here. Right now, my table view uses delegates to update the value in each cell and reload the tableview. When the data model updates some value, the color change of the label will then be reflected in the `cellforRowAt` function

Comment: you have to call your animation function in the `showError()` function

Comment: Thanks. I ended up performing the animation after tableview did `reloadData()` through a delegate function by iterating over all the visible cells using a for loop and iterating over each cell and animating based on each cell